# Create procedure to allow students to register for a course only if they have enough balance

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How to create a procedure to allow students to register for the course only if they have enough balance.

Procedure with parameters for Student id and Course id.
Check if they can register or not according to student balance.

If we have tables like these:

```
courses

c_id    c_cost  c_name  c_hours
1       30          C#    3
2       50         Java   3
3       40          DB    3

students

sid  S_blance   S_name
1     300       john
2     100       sam
3     20         kim

register table

sid S_name  C_cost  C_name
1   john    30      DB
3   sam     30      DB
1   john    50      Java
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a procedure which checks the student's balance against the cost of the course; if they can have enough in their account it registers the student for the course, otherwise it raises an exception.

```
create or replace procedure register_for_course (
     p_S_id in students.s_id%type
     , p_C_id in courses.c_id%type
     )
is
    l_course courses%rowtype;
    l_student students%rowtype;
begin
    select * into l_course
    from courses c
    where c.c_id = p_c_id;

    select * into l_student
    from students s
    where s.s_id = p_s_id
    for update of s_balance;

    if l_course.c_cost > l_student.s_balance then
        raise_application_error(-20000, 
            'student cannot afford to register for this course');
    end if;

    insert into register 
    values (p_s_id, l_student.s_name, l_course.c_cost, l_course.c_name);

    update  students s  
    set s.s_balance = s.s_balance - l_course.c_cost
    where s.s_id = p_s_id;

    commit;

end;
/
```

If you want a routine that just does the checking, you probably need a function which returns a flag. Oracle SQL - like most other RDBMS - doesn't support a Boolean datatype, so if you want to use the function in SQL it will have to return a string.

```
create or replace function can_register_for_course (
     p_S_id in students.s_id%type
     , p_C_id in courses.c_id%type
     ) return varchar2
is
    l_course courses%rowtype;
    l_student students%rowtype;
    rv varchar2(1);
begin
    select * into l_course
    from courses c
    where c.c_id = p_c_id;

    select * into l_student
    from students s
    where s.s_id = p_s_id
    for update of s_balance;

    if l_course.c_cost > l_student.s_balance then
        rv := 'N';
    else
        rv := 'Y';
    end if;

    return rv;

end;
/
```

Checking the reservation in a separate function like this would be inefficient because you would need to query `students` and `courses` again when you come to insert the `register` table. This is because that table is denormalised, with redundant columns. A better data model would be a `register` table with a projection like this `(s_id, c_id)`, which can neatly be enforced as a compound primary key as well as foreign keys to the parent tables.

Answer (score 0):

Create below stored procedure which will return 1 if student can register course else it will return 0

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YourProedure (@sid int, @c_id int)
AS
BEGIN
  IF ((SELECT
      S_balance
    FROM students
    WHERE sid = @sid)
    >= (SELECT
      c_cost
    FROM COURSES
    WHERE c_id = @c_id)
    )
    SELECT
      1 Result
  ELSE
    SELECT
      0 Result
END
```

Comment: This is not Oracle syntax.

Comment: Initially question was sql-server tag.